# how to RegEx names like José González?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to RegEx person's names. José González is very difficult, i guess.
I have found following code, that isn't working

```
preg_match("/^[[:alpha:]'-\s]+$/", $input);
```

I tried to change to

```
preg_match("/^[[:print:]'-\s]+$/", $input);
```

or

```
preg_match("/^[[:alpha:]\`\´-\s]+$/", $input);
```

and

```
preg_match("/^[[:alpha:][:punct:]\`\´-\s]+$/", $input);
```

without success. The only matched chars are "Jos"

Comment: `preg_match` isn't a SQL statement. What does this have to do with SQL? Is this a PHP question?

Comment: this should be a security check before sql insert

Comment: Check this solution to similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20452112/231388

Comment: You mean to prevent sql injections? It's far better, safer, easier *and* faster (more scaleable) to use parameterized queries to do that. A regex may catch some injection attacks but not all. A parameterized query passes the parameters outside the statement, as part of the RPC call, so there is absolutely no way an injection can occur at that level. Of course, if you use string concatenation somewhere else to create some other statement with this value you will be in trouble again. Which is why you shouldn't use string concatenation at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just this regex to match that name:

```
"#[\p{L} ]+#u"
```

- `u` flag is for using unicode characters in regex
- `\p{L}` is matching any word character in unicode